# Mongoose $gte date search returns documents from before that date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema/model with a property of `completedSetup` that is a `Date` type.

Project repo: https://github.com/rmgreenstreet/custom-forms

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Location = require('./location');
const Response = require('./response');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const crypto = require('crypto');


const forbiddenWords = ['realtor', 'realty', 'realestate', 'agent', 'broker', 'admin'];

const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: String,
    personalEmail:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    role:{
        type:String,
        default:'User'
    },
    isCompanyAdmin: {
        type:Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    company: {
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Company'
    },
    location: {
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Location'
    },
    image: {
        url: {
            type:String,
            default:'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
        },
        public_id: String
    },
    isExpedited: {
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    isHidden: {
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    formAccessToken: {
        type: String,
        default: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')
    },
    completedSetup: Date,
    responses: [
        {
            type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'Response'
        }
    ],
    createAccountToken : {
        type: String,
        default: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')
    },
    resetPasswordToken : String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
    created:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    }
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

Querying by `createdDate`:

```js
let beginDate = new Date();
beginDate.setMonth(beginDate.getMonth() - 6);
if (req.body.beginDate) {
    beginDate = new Date(req.body.beginDate);
}
let endDate = new Date();
if (req.body.endDate) {
    endDate = new Date(req.body.endDate);
}

const recentSetups = await User.find({completedSetup: {$gt: beginDate, $lte: endDate}});
```

This returns all `User`s, not just ones with the `completedSetup` between `beginDate` and `endDate`.

The strange thing is that the same query returns correctly on other schemas/models, but their dates are set differently.

On some models I have a `created` property that is set by default to `Date.now()`, that is set at creation, and the query returns those fine.

However seeding data for the `completedSetup` uses a `pickaADate` function that I've defined to choose a date sometime in the previous year, or in the current year up to the current month (this is a portfolio project still in development):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const faker = require('faker');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const Company = require('./models/company');
const Location = require('./models/location');
const User = require('./models/user');
const Form = require('./models/form');
const Question = require('./models/question');
const Response = require('./models/response');

const sampleImages = fs.readdirSync('./public/images/seeds');

function flipACoin() {
    const yesOrNo = Math.floor(Math.random() *2);
    // console.log(yesOrNo);
    return yesOrNo;
}

async function pickADate() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const today = new Date();
            const day = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 27);
            // const thisOrLastYear = flipACoin();
            const month = Math.ceil(Math.random() * today.getMonth())
            const returnDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() - flipACoin(),month,day);
            resolve(returnDate);
            return;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Error creating random date: ${err.message}`);
            reject(Date.now());
            return;
        }
    });
};

async function seedDefaultQuestions() {
    try {
        console.log('clearing all default questions from database')
        await Question.deleteMany({});
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    try {
        console.log('adding default questions to database')
        const defaultQuestionsJSON = await JSON.parse(await fs.readFileSync('./private/defaultQuestions.json'));
        for (let question of defaultQuestionsJSON) {
            // console.log(question);
            await Question.create(question);
        }
        console.log(`${defaultQuestionsJSON.length} default questions added to database`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }

};


async function clearDatabase() {

    console.log('Clearing database \n Clearing Companies');
    await Company.deleteMany({});
    console.log('All Companies deleted \n Clearing Locations');
    await Location.deleteMany({});
    console.log('All Locations deleted \n Clearing Users');
    await User.deleteMany({role: {$ne:'owner'}});
    console.log('All Users deleted \n Clearing Forms');
    await Form.deleteMany({});
    console.log('All forms deleted \n Clearing responses');
    await Response.deleteMany({});
    console.log('Database cleared');

};


async function seedDatabase() {
    // const companyCount = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 200);
    const companyCount = 10;
    const defaultQuestions = await Question.find({isDefault:true});

    async function createLocations(companyId) {
        const locationCount = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
        let locationsArr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < locationCount; i++) {
            let isPrimary = false;
            if (i=== 0) {
                isPrimary = true;
            }
            const randomImageIndex = Math.ceil(Math.random() * sampleImages.length);
            const newLocation = await Location.create({
                primary: isPrimary,
                officeNumber: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000).toString(),
                name: faker.company.companyName(),
                phone: faker.phone.phoneNumber(),
                fax: faker.phone.phoneNumber(),
                address: {
                    streetNumber: Math.random(Math.ceil() * 1000),
                    streetName: faker.address.streetName(),
                    secondary: `Ste ${faker.random.alphaNumeric()}`,
                    city: faker.address.city(),
                    state: faker.address.stateAbbr(),
                    postal: faker.address.zipCode(),
                    country: 'USA'
                },
                website: faker.internet.url(),
                images: [
                    {
                        secure_url:`/images/seeds/${sampleImages[randomImageIndex]}`
                    }
                ],
                company: companyId,
                created: await pickADate()
            });
            await newLocation.save();
            newLocation.contacts = await createUsers(newLocation._id, companyId, 'Admin', (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)));
            await newLocation.save();
            console.log(`Location ${newLocation.name} created with ${newLocation.contacts.length} contacts`)
            await createUsers(newLocation._id, companyId, 'User', (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30)));
            locationsArr.push(newLocation._id);
            await newLocation.addDefaultForm();
        }
        return locationsArr;
    };

    async function createUsers(locationId, companyId, role, count) {
        let contactsArr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            const newFirstName = await faker.name.firstName();
            const newLastName = await faker.name.lastName();
            let newUser;
            try {
                newUser = await User.register({
                firstname: newFirstName,
                lastname: newLastName,
                username: newFirstName+newLastName,
                personalEmail: newFirstName+newLastName+'@test.com',
                role: role,
                company: companyId,
                location: locationId,
                formAccessToken: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex'),
                createAccountToken: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex'),
                created: await pickADate()
            },'password');
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.message.includes('UserExistsError')) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(role === 'User');{
            if(flipACoin()) {
                newUser.responses.push(await createResponse(newUser)); 
                await newUser.save();
            } else {
                continue;
            }                
            if(flipACoin()) {
                newUser.completedSetup = await pickADate(); 
                await newUser.save();
            } else {
                continue;
            }                
        };
        contactsArr.push(newUser._id);
        console.log(`${role} ${newUser.firstname} ${newUser.lastname} created`);
        };
        return contactsArr;
    };

    async function createResponse(user) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Creating a response for ${user.firstname}`)
            const makeString = (charLimit) => {
                let str = faker.lorem.paragraph()
                    if (str.length > charLimit) {
                        str = str.slice(0, charLimit - 1)
                    }
                    return str
                }
            let response = await Response.create({owner:user._id, created:await pickADate()});
            try {
                for (let question of defaultQuestions) {
                    const answer = {
                        questionId: question._id
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Checkbox') {
                        answer.value = true;
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Email') {
                        answer.value = faker.internet.email();
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'File') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Image') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Number') {
                        answer.value = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 99);
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Password') {
                        answer.value = 'Pa55w0rd123';
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Radio') {
                        question.value = 'No';
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Select') {
                        question.value = "At&t";
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Tel') {
                        answer.value = faker.phone.phoneNumber();
                    }
                    if (question.inputType == 'Text') {
                        if(question.maxLength) {
                            answer.value = makeString(question.maxLength);
                        } else {
                            answer.value = faker.lorem.words()
                        }
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Textarea') {
                        answer.value = faker.lorem.paragraph();
                    }
                    if(question.inputType == 'Url') {
                        answer.value = faker.internet.url();
                    }
                    response.answers.push(answer);
                }
                await response.save();
                resolve(response._id);
                return;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(`Error creating random response: ${err.message}.`);
                reject(response);
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    console.log(`Creating ${companyCount} companies`)
    for(let i = 0; i < companyCount; i++) {
        const newCompany = await Company.create({
            name: faker.company.companyName(),
            created: await pickADate()
        });
        newCompany.locations = await createLocations(newCompany._id);
        await newCompany.save();
        console.log(`${newCompany.name} created with ${newCompany.locations.length} locations`)
    }
    console.log('database seeded')
};

module.exports = {seedDatabase, clearDatabase, seedDefaultQuestions};
```

I'm thinking the issue is in that function generating a random date from the beginning of last year up to the current date, but I honestly can't see how `new Date(yyyy`(integer)`,monthIndex,day)` would be any different from the date created by `Date.now()`, according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date under "Individual Date and Time Component Values"

Here is how the User data looks in MongoDB, the `completedSetup` property is the last one, and it looks to be formatted correctly:

[image]

Lastly, here is the log of some of what the query returns (hit the character limit with all of it):

```js
[
{
    image: {
      url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
    },
    role: 'Admin',
    isCompanyAdmin: false,
    isExpedited: false,
    isHidden: false,
    formAccessToken: 'de5459c2cbf3ca1cbdb0a5daceb6ab61',
    responses: [ 5e8b71b7e75a0726242637b9 ],
    createAccountToken: 'a826054b8055243c52247a656eed9340',
    created: 2020-03-04T06:00:00.000Z,
    _id: 5e8b71b6e75a0726242637b8,
    firstname: 'Larue',
    lastname: 'Armstrong',
    username: 'LarueArmstrong',
    personalEmail: 'LarueArmstrong@test.com',
    company: 5e8b71abe75a072624263688,
    location: 5e8b71b6e75a0726242637b5,
    __v: 1,
    completedSetup: 2020-03-07T06:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    image: {
      url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
    },
    role: 'User',
    isCompanyAdmin: false,
    isExpedited: false,
    isHidden: false,
    formAccessToken: '7bf9d040c0009691191f3122c14d3d51',
    responses: [ 5e8b71c2e75a07262426392a ],
    createAccountToken: 'b284c3f43fad0081f967f06926ee1d6d',
    created: 2019-11-25T06:00:00.000Z,
    _id: 5e8b71c1e75a072624263929,
    firstname: 'Lance',
    lastname: 'Wolff',
    username: 'LanceWolff',
    personalEmail: 'LanceWolff@test.com',
    company: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638dd,
    location: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638de,
    __v: 1,
    completedSetup: 2020-03-02T06:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    image: {
      url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
    },
    role: 'User',
    isCompanyAdmin: false,
    isExpedited: false,
    isHidden: false,
    formAccessToken: '319cd6d626a48617c012be6c25fe66a8',
    responses: [ 5e8b71c5e75a072624263977 ],
    createAccountToken: '43e9161a30f7ebd672315c761da9e3d7',
    created: 2019-06-03T05:00:00.000Z,
    _id: 5e8b71c5e75a072624263976,
    firstname: 'Kailey',
    lastname: 'Ruecker',
    username: 'KaileyRuecker',
    personalEmail: 'KaileyRuecker@test.com',
    company: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638dd,
    location: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638de,
    __v: 1,
    completedSetup: 2020-02-23T06:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    image: {
      url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
    },
    role: 'User',
    isCompanyAdmin: false,
    isExpedited: false,
    isHidden: false,
    formAccessToken: 'ccb5fc2c6ff671a8cb5bdcf432cbcb1b',
    responses: [ 5e8b71c7e75a0726242639bd ],
    createAccountToken: '8d3aa2ecd6e0da797d8cbf9846c78c9b',
    created: 2019-04-20T05:00:00.000Z,
    _id: 5e8b71c6e75a0726242639bc,
    firstname: 'Skyla',
    lastname: 'Dicki',
    username: 'SkylaDicki',
    personalEmail: 'SkylaDicki@test.com',
    company: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638dd,
    location: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638de,
    __v: 1,
    completedSetup: 2019-10-22T05:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    image: {
      url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
    },
    role: 'User',
    isCompanyAdmin: false,
    isExpedited: false,
    isHidden: false,
    formAccessToken: '0641d2cf09459724ffea35d5cc96e2f1',
    responses: [ 5e8b71c7e75a0726242639e0 ],
    createAccountToken: '0f5e1bfd23df18835378c314efbcb206',
    created: 2019-12-02T06:00:00.000Z,
    _id: 5e8b71c7e75a0726242639df,
    firstname: 'Rasheed',
    lastname: 'Walsh',
    username: 'RasheedWalsh',
    personalEmail: 'RasheedWalsh@test.com',
    company: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638dd,
    location: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638de,
    __v: 1,
    completedSetup: 2020-02-16T06:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    image: {
      url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
    },
    role: 'User',
    isCompanyAdmin: false,
    isExpedited: false,
    isHidden: false,
    formAccessToken: '7f584ded07bfe5b20e95ef72ed2a7749',
    responses: [ 5e8b71cae75a072624263a2b ],
    createAccountToken: '0934cd5e7ccb75d476ecc23624e491f1',
    created: 2020-02-27T06:00:00.000Z,
    _id: 5e8b71cae75a072624263a2a,
    firstname: 'Leanna',
    lastname: 'Kuphal',
    username: 'LeannaKuphal',
    personalEmail: 'LeannaKuphal@test.com',
    company: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638dd,
    location: 5e8b71bfe75a0726242638de,
    __v: 1,
    completedSetup: 2019-11-02T05:00:00.000Z
  }
]
```

In the full list (something like 60+ results) several are before 11/2019, like the one in this snippet that is from 10/2019.

Comment: Are you able to investigate the data in the `users` collection to see what dates you actually have in the `completedSetup` field? Can you show the code where you are using `pickaADate` to seed the `completedSetup`?

Comment: Also, the code for `pickADate` is not valid. There is a `}` too many just before the catch it seems. Did something go missing when you entered/pasted it perhaps? If so, please correct in the question.

Comment: @abondoa updated :) replaced 'pickADate' with full seeds function, added mongoDB screenshot and query return log

Comment: Also added link to project repo: https://github.com/rmgreenstreet/custom-forms

Comment: Thanks :) Can you share the values of the query (`beginDate` and `endDate`) used to get the results in your "Lastly, here is the log of some of what..."? Looking through the results there it seems that all entries have `completedSetup`within the default bounds of your query (within the last 6 months).

Comment: @abondoa `beginDate` is today -6 months by default (so november) and `endDate` is today, by default. Haven't added any inputs to change those yet. Updated returned values to include the ones previously removed to meet the character limit, and removed ones that fit date range (all from the same result)

Comment: The results still looks acceptable to me :) Note that `let beginDate = new Date();
beginDate.setMonth(beginDate.getMonth() - 6);` gets you the date "Mon Oct 07 2019"  (so October, not November).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211166/discussion-between-r-greenstreet-and-abondoa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I feel dumb now that I've found the issue.

The problem was in the `getPoints` function.

It was treating every item in every sub-array it received as a point, and creating a point for it. So if the `graphDatasets` looked like:

```js
[
    ['Invitations','Completions','Setups'],
    [/* actual points data */]
]
```

And the points data had 7 months worth in it, it was adding 3 more points to the `points` array, extending the number of points.

I had to completely rewrite the structure of `graphDatasets` and update the `renderCanvas` function accordingly:

```js
/* Don't know why I didn't have this as arrays of objects before, it's so much simpler */
const graphDatasets = [
              [
                {label:'Invitations',payload:recentInvitations,searchProperty:'created'},
                {label:'Completions',payload:recentCompletions,searchProperty:'created'},
                {label:'Setups',payload:recentSetups,searchProperty:'completedSetup'}
              ],
              [
                {label:'Companies',payload:recentCompanies,searchProperty:'created'},
                {label:'Locations',payload:recentLocations,searchProperty:'created'}
              ]             
            ];
```

```js
//converts full object data from server into {month: String, count: Number} objects
//Add searchProperty argument
function getPoints(items, searchProperty) {
    let points = [];
//access the data to be turned into points using the value at the .payload property
    items.payload.forEach((item) => {
        /* find the date to compare against using the searchProperty provided */
        const workingDate = new Date(item[searchProperty])
        const monthYear = `${workingDate.getMonth() + 1}/${workingDate.getFullYear()}`;
        let existingPoint = points.find(point => point.x === monthYear);
        if (existingPoint) {
            existingPoint.y ++;
        } else {
            points.push({x:monthYear, y: 1});
        }
    });
    return points;
};

// Returns the max Y value in our data list
 function getMaxY(data) {
    var max = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        if(data[i].y > max) {
            max = data[i].y;
        }
    }
    max += 10 - max % 10;
    return max;
}
/* Removes objects from combined data where month matches, in order to draw only one copy of that 
month on the X axis */
function removeDuplicates(originalArray, objKey) {
    var trimmedArray = [];
    var values = [];
    var value;

    for(var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
      value = originalArray[i][objKey];
      if(values.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        trimmedArray.push(originalArray[i]);
        values.push(value);
      }
    }
    return trimmedArray;
};

/* compare two arrays and if there are any missing months in either array, add them with a y value of 0, then sortby month/year */
function equalize(arr1, arr2) {
    let newArr = arr2.reduce(function (result, obj2) {
        if (arr1.some(obj1 => obj1['x'] === obj2['x'])) {
            return result;
        }
        return [...result, {'x' : obj2['x'], 'y':0}];
    }, arr1);
    newArr.sort(function (a, b) {
        a = a.x.split('/');
        b = b.x.split('/')
        return new Date(a[1], a[0], 1) - new Date(b[1], b[0], 1)
    });
    return newArr;
};

function renderCanvas(canvas, data) {
    console.log('drawing on canvas');
    const colors = ['indigo','blue','green','orange','purple','teal','fuschia'];

    if(canvas.getContext) {
        var xPadding = 30;
        var yPadding = 30;
        var xLength = canvas.width - yPadding;
        var yLength = canvas.height - xPadding;
        var pointsArr = [];
        data.forEach(function (obj) {
            pointsArr.push(getPoints(obj, obj.searchProperty));
        });
        for (let i = 0; i < pointsArr.length -1 ; i++) {
            pointsArr[i] = equalize(pointsArr[i], pointsArr[i+1]);
        };
        var combinedData = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], pointsArr);
        combinedData.sort(function(a,b) {
            return new Date(a.created) - new Date(b.created)
        });
        var filteredPoints = removeDuplicates(combinedData, 'x');

        /* cuts X axis into a number of sections double the number of points */ 
        var xSpacing = xLength / (filteredPoints.length * 2);

        var yMax = getMaxY(combinedData);

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.font = 'italic 8pt sans-serif';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 6;
        ctx.moveTo(yPadding,0);
        ctx.lineTo(yPadding,yLength);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,yLength);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

        // Return the y pixel for a graph point
        function getYPixel(val) {
            return yLength - ((yLength / yMax) * (val));
        }

        // Return the y pixel for a graph point
        function getXPixel(val) {
            return ((xSpacing + yPadding) + (xSpacing * (2 * val)))
        }

        function drawLine(points, color, legendVal) {

            /* move one xSpacing out from y Axis */
            ctx.moveTo(yPadding + xSpacing, getYPixel(points[0].y));
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle=color;
            ctx.strokeStyle=color;
            points.forEach((point) => {
                const x = getXPixel(points.indexOf(point));
                const y = (getYPixel(point.y)) ;
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.lineTo(x,y);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,360,false);
                ctx.fillText(point.y, x + 2, y - 15);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.moveTo(x,y);
            });
            /* will need to update this (and other stuff) but use the label property of the data to label the line on the graph */
            ctx.moveTo(canvas.width - yPadding, getYPixel(points[points.length-1].y));
            ctx.fillText(legendVal, canvas.width - 20, getYPixel(points[points.length-1].y));
        }

        // Draw the X value texts
        for(var i = 0; i < filteredPoints.length; i ++) {
            if (i===0) {
                ctx.fillText(filteredPoints[i].x, yPadding, yLength +20);
            }else {
                ctx.fillText(filteredPoints[i].x, (yPadding) + (xSpacing * (2 * i)), yLength + 20);
            }
        }

        // Draw the Y value texts
        ctx.textAlign = "right"
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

        for(var i = 0; i <= yMax; i += 10) {
            if (i === yMax) {
                ctx.fillText(i, xPadding - 10, getYPixel(i-1));
            } else {
                ctx.fillText(i, xPadding - 10, getYPixel(i));
            }
        };

        pointsArr.forEach(async function (points) {
            drawLine(points, colors[pointsArr.indexOf(points)], data[pointsArr.indexOf(points)].label);
        });
    }
};


NodeList.prototype.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf
canvases.forEach((canvas) => {
    renderCanvas(
        canvas,
        graphDatasets[canvases.indexOf(canvas)]
        );
});
```